# TypeScript: How to bind type declaration to import statement

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I'm trying to create a type definition for [es6-promisify](https://github.com/digitaldesignlabs/es6-promisify), a JS package not in the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/) annotations repository. Looking at examples in DefinitelyTyped and following [TS Deep Dive / Declaration Files](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html), I created a crude annotation that I saved in my project in a `vendor.d.ts`:

```
declare function promisify(original: (...args: any[]) => any, settings: any): Promise<any>

export = promisify
// export interface promisify { } // or should I do an interface?
```

Now, considering I import with `import promisify = require('es6-promisify')`, how do I tell TypeScript that the `promisify` import is annotated in `vendor.d.ts`? Currently, `tsc` keeps returning `Could not find a declaration file for module 'es6-promisify'. 'promisify.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.` I'm trying to digest [TS Docs / Module Resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) but am failing at it so far.

Phrased differently: what's the mechanism used by TypeScript to resolve a declaration file from an import? [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) warning: maybe I'm doing things wrong and shouldn't do a `vendor.d.ts`? Maybe there's a good reason `es6-promisify` is not in DT? Feel free to contradict with better ways to reach my goal of making tsc with `"noImplicitAny": true` happy. Thanks :)

Comment: Have you already tried renaming `vendor.d.ts` to `es6-promisify.d.ts`, and adding the directory containing the type definition it to `compilerOptions.typeRoots` in your `tsconfig`? If you are changing `compilerOptions.typeRoots`, don't forget to add `./node_modules/@types` to it. refer: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: @SayanPal thanks; tried that, but I must still be doing something wrong, my import keeps failing to get types in vscode. Any method/tool to help me troubleshoot where the problem is? (config? declaration? something else?)

Comment: Not sure, you may try updating the TypeScript version and referring the correct version from vscode. It may happen that vscode is raising some false positive due to version mismatch, which might not be a run-time issue at the end. The error may also caused by how you are importing the module in your TypeScript code. It would be better if you post that code fragment as well.

Comment: @SayanPal thanks for the fast reponse :) . Well I'm using the latest TS 2.3.2, and sorry, which code fragment do you need? My post details both the declaration and the `import` line. Note: an additional thing I just tried: following DT's structure (example of such a [simple typing that works: mkdirp](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/mkdirp)) with an `es6-promisify` folder and `index.d.ts` + `tsconfig.json` files inside. Still failing :-/

Comment: My bad, missed the import. Please check if my posted answer helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me.

`es6-promisifiy.d.ts`:

```
declare module "es6-promisify" {
  export default function promisify(original: (...args: any[]) => any, settings: any): Promise<any>
}
```

usage:

```
import promisify from "es6-promisify";
...
const xyz = promisify(whatever, whatever);
```

`tsconfig.json:`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types",
            "./custom_typings"
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yay! Works great (except the typing is bad, but now I can iterate on it ). Looks like the declaration I shared missed wrapping the `export` in a `declare module` block. But then I don't understand why [the mkdirp typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mkdirp/index.d.ts) work without `declare module`, any idea? Thanks again!

Comment: @RonanJouchet Not exactly sure, but my closest guess is this depends on the module system (and resolution) you are using. But again, I am not sure. Maybe try opening a new question, and I will subscribe, as I am also interested to know the answer :) Have fun